# Conda install conflicting requirements

Tags: python, installation, pip, pytorch, conda

I am attempting to use Conda to create an environment from a Pip requirements file. The contents of the file are

**requirements.txt**

```
numpy==1.18.2
torch==1.4.0
torchvision==0.5.0
scikit-learn==0.22.2.post1
Pillow==8.3.2
pydicom==1.4.2
pandas==1.0.3
```

Running the command

```bash
conda create -n $name --file requirements.txt
```

gives a `PackageNotFound` error as the channels are missing.

How do I amend this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Possible Issues

There are a few potential issues.

### Conda `pytorch`

First, not all packages in Conda go by the same name as they do in other repositories. Part of this is due to the nature of Conda being a general package repository, rather than a language-specific one. In particular, the `torch` module is delivered via the Conda `pytorch` package.

So that has to change.

### NumPy version unavailable

That particular build of NumPy does not appear to be available in either **defaults** or **conda-forge** channels.

```bash
$ mamba search numpy=1.18.2
No match found for: numpy=1.18.2. Search: *numpy*=1.18.2

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - numpy=1.18.2

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/bioconda/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
```

**Why would this happen?** For most Python packages, Conda works downstream of the PyPI repository. When new releases come out, the Conda Forge bot (for example) will auto-generate a pull request to corresponding feedstock. Sometimes these don't "just work" and need some troubleshooting to get built. Occasionally, the process to get the builds working won't finish before a new release hits. This results in a newer pull request superceding the previous one, and can lead to the old pull request being abandoned. This results in gaps in the coverage of PyPI by Conda Forge, and is [exactly what happened here](https://github.com/conda-forge/numpy-feedstock/pull/187).

If you can tolerate a different version, **conda-forge** does provide v1.18.1 (below) and v1.18.4 (above).

Otherwise, if you require exact replication of package versions, then you will have to source this from PyPI. I'll show this in the end.

### Channel issues

#### Missing channels

OP does not indicate the channel configuration. The `torchvision==0.5.0` package, for example, only is available through the **pytorch** channel.

#### Masked channels

Another issue here could be the use of the `channel_priority: strict` setting. If this setting were used, it is possible a channel with the version required might be *a priori* excluded by the SAT solver simply because the package (but not the correct version) is available in a higher priority channel. These days `channel_priority: flexible` is the default and can be set with:

```bash
conda config --set channel_priority flexible
```

## Solutions

### Exact replication (PyPI only)

Give the package names and versions, these packages likely originated from PyPI. If you need to exactly replicate the original environment - say, for reproducing scientific results - then I'd recommend sourcing everything from PyPI. The best way to do this is to use Conda to source Python and Pip, then let Pip install the `requirements.txt`.

Judging from the package versions, we're talking Python 3.7 or 3.8. You'd probably be fine with just `python=3.8`, but [a precise guesstimate [from release dates](https://www.python.org/downloads/) would be `python=3.8.2`. So, try something like:

**environment.yaml**

```yaml
name: my_env
channels:
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.8.2
  - pip
  - pip:
    - -r requirements.txt
```

Then create the environment with

```bash
conda env create -n $name -f environment.yaml
```

making sure the `requirements.txt` is in the folder with the YAML.

If adding packages to this environment later, I would recommend only using `pip install`. Otherwise, [Conda may have issues](https://www.anaconda.com/blog/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment).

### Conda-only environment

Assuming the `numpy=1.18.2` can be substituted, a Conda-only environment might be something like:

**environment.yaml**

```yaml
name: my_env
channels:
  - pytorch
  - conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python=3.8
  - numpy=1.18.1  # alternatively, 1.18.4
  - pytorch=1.4.0
  - torchvision=0.5.0
  - scikit-learn=0.22.2.post1
  - pillow=8.3.2
  - pydicom=1.4.2
  - pandas=1.0.3
```

Again, creating with:

```bash
conda env create -n $name -f environment.yaml
```

Note that in YAML only one `=` is used. This would be the best approach if you plan to install additional packages through Conda in an *ad hoc* manner (e.g., `conda install`).

### Mixed Conda-Pip environment

You could also try a mixed environment mostly similar to the last one, but having Pip specifically provide `numpy==1.18.2`. I wouldn't recommend this, since the other dependencies with definitely bring in NumPy first from Conda, and then Pip will clobber it to provide the exact version.