# Why some specific versions of packages are not available in conda channels

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda, conda

I'm trying to run a project downloaded from github. According to the readme file, I need to configure it with python 3.6 and some other version specific packges. Two of them are `numpy==1.18.2` and `scikit-learn==0.22.2`.

I create a new python 3.6 conda environment and install all needed packaged with `conda install`. However, when I install `numpy` and `scikit-learn`(e.g. using `conda install -c conda-forge numpy==1.18.2`), a `PackagesNotFoundError` raised.

```
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - numpy==1.18.2

Current channels:

  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/win-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Then I run `conda search numpy` to list all versions of numpy which are available in conda channels. And I find that there are not version 1.18.2 for numpy.

`conda search conda-forge::numpy` returns

```
(...)
numpy                         1.17.5  py38h95a1406_0  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.1  py36h7314795_1  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.1  py36h95a1406_0  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.1  py36he0f5f23_1  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.1  py37h8960a57_1  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.1  py37h95a1406_0  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.1  py38h8854b6b_1  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.1  py38h95a1406_0  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.4  py36h7314795_0  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.4  py36he0f5f23_0  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.4  py37h8960a57_0  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.4  py38h8854b6b_0  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.5  py36h7314795_0  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.5  py36he0f5f23_0  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.5  py37h8960a57_0  conda-forge
numpy                         1.18.5  py38h8854b6b_0  conda-forge
numpy                         1.19.0  py36h7314795_0  conda-forge
(...)
```

which implys that version 1.18.2 and 1.18.3 are both skipped.

The official website of numpy show that version 1.18.2 has indeed been released. However, it's not available in conda channels. Although I know that there would not be too many differences between version 1.18.2 and 1.18.x (which means I could use other 1.18.x version instead). But I just wonder **why some versions are not included in conda channels?**

Comment: Answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72342988/17797688) (NumPy version unavailable - Why would this happen?)